# How to create session onclick of hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net

I have created one page.In that there are 2 menu.One for pass student and other for fail student.Onclick of pass student shows studentid,rollno,batch and all subject list in grid.Grid column are dynamically changes.
Onclick of fail student just displaying rollno,batch and fail in which subject.
Inrowbound event dynamically added hyperlink to studentid for pass student.Onclick of hyperlink,new window get opened.So I passed studentid in form of querystring for fetching all detail of selected student and hide toolbar of window.Admin can modify that record.I used studentid in the form of qurystring.I want to use that value in session.How can I do that?
In rowbound event I added like this

```
if(e.Rows.Cell.Count == 6)
{
 Hyperlink hy = new hyperlink();
 e.Row.Cell[0].Controls.Add(hy);
 hy.Attributes.Add("Onclick","Return showdetail('"+e.Row.cell[0].Text+"')")
}
```

// In aspx page -- In javascript

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
showdetail(Studentid)
{
  Window.Open("samplepage.aspx?id="+Studentid+","win32","toolbar=no,resizeable=1");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Make AJAX call to page method and set session variable there.

Comment: Sorry I did not get this.Can u pls tell in brief?

Comment: See my answer posted below.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
showdetail(Studentid)
{
<%=Session["sid"]=Studentid %>
  Window.Open("samplepage.aspx?id="+Studentid+","win32","toolbar=no,resizeable=1");
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can not assign value to session variable here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make ajax call. For simplicity i am using jquery file here. Just you need to include jquery.1.9.1.js in the header sections and you can modify your `showdetail` function as below

**AJAX CALL IN ASPX/JS**

```
Showdetail(Studentid)
{
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
                url: "Home.aspx/AssignSession",
                data: "{'stdid':'" + Studentid + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(res) {
if(res.d=="Success")
                      window.Open("samplepage.aspx","win32","toolbar=no,resizeable=1");
                }
            });
```

**PAGE METHOD IN CODE BEHIND**

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string AssignSession(string stdid)
        {
HttpContext.Current.Session["stdid"]=stdid;
return "Success";
    }
```

Now you can access this session variable `Session["stdid"]` anywhere(samplepage.aspx) in your application. This will meet you requirement.